# Viewer settings panel getContentSize() returns zero height

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to open the settings dialog panel through a custom menu.

```
function showSettingsPanel(visible) {
    if (visible) {
        viewer.viewerSettingsPanel.syncUI();
    }

    viewer.viewerSettingsPanel.setVisible(visible, true);
    if (visible) {
        viewer.viewerSettingsPanel.resizeToContent();
    }
}
```

`resizeToContent()` fails, and draws the tabbed area with zero height.  It appears to be because I have no tab selected.

The cause is in `Autodesk.Viewing.UI.SettingsPanel.prototype.getContentSize` in viewer3D.js version 3.1.1 at line 38452

```
var selectedTab = this.panelTabs.length > this.panelTabs[0] ? 0 : null;
```

which doesn't default to the first tab, and should be

```
var selectedTab = this.panelTabs.length > 0 ? this.panelTabs[0] : null;
```

Currently my workaround is to force the tab selection every time the panel is made visible, but hopefully this will be fixed upstream?

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you for your post, let me check with our engineers about this so I can update you better with a solution.

Comment: Haven't got anything from the engineers yet, but A few newer version have been release that might have fixed this. Can you confirm this is still happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been fixed between version 3.3 and version 4.0.